# Why isn't it possible to split a string stored in an array and place it back inside of that array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, storage

```
public class Loopname{

public static void main (String [] args){

String files []= new String [] {"Hello Hola Bonjour"};

String delimiter= " ";

files[]=files[0].split(delimiter);
}
 }
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not possible? If you know of any alternate ways of doing this please share. I am open to any tips and words of advice. I am a newbie, but I am willing to learn. Please help me. Thanks in advance?

Comment: `files = files[0].split(delimiter);`

Comment: @bernie - it is not possible because the source array has size 1, the split is an array of size 3 and arrays can't resize in Java ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "[]" is part of the variable type, not the name. You can do:

```
String[] files= new String [] {"Hello Hola Bonjour"};
String delimiter= " ";
files = files[0].split(delimiter);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Are you a student?

Comment: This is not exactly "placed back in the same array". A new array has been created and assigned to the `files` variable. - But I guess, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

On the last line, change `files[]` to `files`. I think that should work then. But really, there's no reason to store the original String in the array. You could do something like

```
String fileString = "Hello Hola Bonjour";
String delimiter = " ";
String[] files = fileString.split(delimiter);
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is just the [] with the second reference to files